# JPA, get all elements

Tags: sql, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm using JPA  and I get all elements from DB in this code:

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
// read the existing entries and write to console
Query q = em.createQuery("select s from Supporter s");
List<Supporter> supportersList = new ArrayList<Supporter>();
supportersList = q.getResultList();
```

And the question is how to get data in more elegant way, I mean without `createQuery("select s from Supporter s");`
As I remember there are somewhere methods like findAll or getAll to use in JPA when case is 'clear' and we don't need native queries.

Comment: There is no "findAll" method in JPA API. Spring Data JPA has one but that is NOT the JPA API, and it is hardly "more elegant", simply hiding JPA API code and making the user further from the real code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a type safe criteria:

```
public List<Supporter> findAll() {
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Supporter> cq = cb.createQuery(Supporter.class);
    Root<Supporter> rootEntry = cq.from(Supporter.class);
    CriteriaQuery<Supporter> all = cq.select(rootEntry);
    TypedQuery<Supporter> allQuery = em.createQuery(all);
    return allQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all entries for a table,

@NamedQuery can also be used as follows

1. Defining a named query annotation for a particular table.

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="getallpeople", query="select p from People p")
public class People {
    //...
}
```

2. Using a defined name query for a select query from the Repository class for your table

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PeopleRepository {

@PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

public List<People> fetchAll() {

TypedQuery<Player> query1 = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getallpeople", People.class);

return query1.getResultList(); 
}
```